# DIV is not resizing properly with the page aspect

Tags: javascript, css

So, I'm trying to create a sketch pad and I'm at the stage where I created the squares, I linked to functions of colouring the squares with DOM and linked a function that creates as many squares as user wants but when I resize the page(mobile, less than normal full screen), the DIV or full square just spreads vertically instead of keeping the same aspect.

https://jsfiddle.net/cpv8Lqj0/

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

I tried with auto height and width, no answer.

Comment: Is the row suppose to be coloured ?

Comment: `cell.style.width = ${600 / gridAmount}px` — You would want your number to be set dynamically depending of the viewheight of the screen.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question, and not any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a codesandbox based on your jsfiddle. I've fixed the javascript where only `.cell` is able to fill in color.

For `css` wise, you can utilize `flex` box. You can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container).
I've also added some `transition` for your cell to make it look nicer. Of course this is optional.

### CSS

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: background 0.75s ease-out;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

### Javascript

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

const makeGrid = gridAmount => {
  for (let i = 0; i < gridAmount; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("div");
    row.classList.add("row");
    container.appendChild(row);

    for (let j = 0; j < gridAmount; j++) {
      const cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.classList.add("cell");

      // add event listener to cell only
      cell.addEventListener("mouseover", handleOnCellMouseOver);

      cell.style.width = `${600 / gridAmount}px`;
      cell.style.height = `${600 / gridAmount}px`;
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
};

const handleOnCellMouseOver = e => {
  const color = getColor();
  e.target.style.background = color;
};

makeGrid(14);

const getColor = () => {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 + 1);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 + 1);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 + 1);
  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
};
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-grid-canvas-1rbj8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. You should provide your code here, within your answer, and not a link to any third party  site.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer The question itself is off topic by violating the same rule.

Comment: Provide context for links.
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

CSS does have a grid system, you can use that for your solution (is cleaner). And it will solve the problem of vertical spreading.
You can find more info about CSS grid at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

I have added a grid system to your code and used a part of @dev_junwen`s JavaScript.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

const makeGrid = gridAmount => {
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = 'repeat(' + gridAmount + ', '+600/gridAmount+'px)';
  container.style.gridTemplateRows = 'repeat(' + gridAmount + ', '+600/gridAmount+'px)';
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.pow(gridAmount, 2); i++) {
      const cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.classList.add("cell");
      cell.addEventListener("mouseover", handleOnCellMouseOver);
      cell.style.minWidth = '100%';
      cell.style.minHeight = '100%';
      container.appendChild(cell);
  }
};

const handleOnCellMouseOver = e => {
  const color = getColor();
  e.target.style.background = color;
};

makeGrid(16);

const getColor = () => {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 + 1);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 + 1);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 + 1);
  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
};
```

```css
.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!-- Auto fill by JS -->
</div>
```

You can also see a demo on my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tmach/pen/MWWZBXy).